# Desactivated environment in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

When running a notebook on Colab i get the message:

"desactivated execution environment"

and the execution stops.

Note that i disconnected from colab then reconnected gain just before running this notebook.

Any idea of the problem ?

thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are having a similar issue, and it's probably due to memory. The session will just disconnect and you have to start the run all over again.

The 2 things I did to somewhat reduce the times this occurs is:

1. before I start or restart running my code I run the below "kill" command. This basically clears any potential items left behind in memory.

   ```
   !kill -9 -1
   ```
2. I use python so every now and then I run the below garbage collector.

   ```
   gc.collect()
   ```

This helps, but not bulletproof.